# NodeJS UTF8 Encoding A Buffer Then Decoding That UTF8 String Produces A Buffer With Different Content

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer

I typed this into the nodejs console

```
new Buffer(new Buffer([0xde]).toString('utf8'), 'utf8')
```

and it prints out

```
<Buffer ef bf bd>
```

After looking at the [docs](http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer)
it seems that this would produce an identical buffer. I'm creating a utf8 encoded string from a buffer whose contents consist of one byte (0xde) then using that utf8 encoded string to create a buffer. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4):

For encodings that can be multi-byte, you cannot expect to get the same bytes back that you started with in all cases. In the case of [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#Description), some characters require more than one byte to be represented properly.

In your example, `0xde` exceeds `0x7f` which is the largest value for a character that can be represented by a single byte. So when you then call `.toString('utf8')`, node sees that it only has one byte and instead returns the UTF-8 character `\uFFFD` (`0xef, 0xbf, 0xbd` in hex) which is used to denote an unknown/unrepresentable character. Then reading back in this "replacement character" value back into a new Buffer is no problem, as it is a valid UTF-8 character.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. For my purposes it sounds like I need to use another type of string encoding option like hex or base64.